# Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line WMIC to extract properties in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scripting, wmic

I have a question.

I would like to extract from different PCs -  from always the same path (let’s say D:\Data or D:) - some properties from files which have the extension *.raw.

I would like to have at the and a txt  or csv file saved to another folder (let’s say to a network folder K:\Results) with the name of the *raw files and their properties.

I am interested mainly in "Created", "Last Modified", "Last Accessed".

I have just discovered the WMIC command, and I would like to use it but I have really no clue how to do a script that I could run from the PCs that:

1 – It gets the list of `*.raw` files in `D:\`

2 – It extracts from all of them `Caption,CreationDate,LastModified`...

3 – It saves me the list with a certain name in `K:\Results\`

Can someone help me?

I am trying to understand more about this Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line, but I am still at:

```
wmic datafile where (drive="C:" and path="\\temp\\") get Caption,CreationDate,LastModified
```

and it can take ages until I solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this community isnt about windows ... its about **programming**. WMIC is a proprietary microsoft tool for WMI interfacing, basically, you're asking about commandline-parameter help. Just saying.

Comment: Hi Specializt, Just I thought it's about Windows. I will change it to "Hello everybody" and better define the tags.

Comment: Well, to add the tag "commandline-parameter" you need 1500 points reputation. I will try again in 34 years.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have some `*.raw` files in your `c:\temp` folder , so

You can try like that :

```
@echo off
Set Output=Result.txt
Set Ext=raw
If Exist %OutPut% Del %OutPut%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "Skip=2 tokens=2-4 delims=," %%a in ('wmic datafile where (drive^="C:" and path^="\\temp\\" AND Extension^="%Ext%"^) get Caption^,CreationDate^,LastModified /format:csv') Do (
    set "file=%%a" 
    set "CreationDate=%%b"
    set "LastModified=%%c"
    (
        echo "!file!"
        echo CreationDate :
        Call:ConvertDate !CreationDate!  
        echo LastModified :
        Call:ConvertDate !LastModified!
        echo ***************************
    )>>%OutPut%
)
EndLocal
if Exist %OutPut% Start "" %OutPut%
Exit /b
::**********************************************************************
Rem Function for Converting WMI Dates to a Standard Date-Time Format
:ConvertDate <Date>
(
    echo WScript.echo WMIDateStringToDate("%~1"^)
    echo Function WMIDateStringToDate(Mydate^)
    echo  WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(Mydate, 5, 2^) ^& "/" ^& _
    echo  Mid(Mydate, 7, 2^) ^& "/" ^& Left(Mydate, 4^) _
    echo  ^& " " ^& Mid (Mydate, 9, 2^) ^& ":" ^& _
    echo  Mid(Mydate, 11, 2^) ^& ":" ^& Mid(Mydate,13, 2^)^)
    echo End Function
)>"%~n0.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%~n0.vbs" "%~1"
Del "%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::**********************************************************************
```

Comment: I have put 4 *.raws in C:\temp and I am getting an empty Result.txt table with: !file!
CreationDate :
LastModified :
*************************** What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: @Beginner You should write `Set Ext=raw` and not `Set Ext=*.raw` in the main script i tested it before posting it to you and it works for me !

Comment: Hi Hackoo, thank you, but it was still not working for me, probably some other beginner error. There is some contraindication in just using something like:                                                                                              wmic /output:F:\Log5.csv datafile where (drive^="F:" and path^="\\Temp\\" AND Extension^="raw") get Caption, CreationDate ,LastModified  /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-us\csv"

Comment: @Beginner `@echo off & wmic datafile where (drive^="F:" and path^="\\temp\\" AND Extension^="raw"^) get Caption^,CreationDate^,LastModified /format:csv & pause`

Comment: the comment-section isnt meant to be filled with code segments ... change your answer or use pastebin

Comment: @specializt Ok and you should upvote it in this case :)